# How to display Unicode symbols of playing card in Python to the terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, backslash

Why doesn't this work? I remove an extra backslash in a data file, but the Unicode characters are not displayed in the console?

```
import re 
file = open("arrayOfCards",'r')
while True:
    next_line = file.readline()
    if not next_line:
        break;
    d = next_line.split(',')
    print (re.sub(r'\'','',d[2]))
file.close()

card = ['A','diamonds','\U0001F0C1','14']
print (type(card[2]), card[2])
```

file arrayOfCards:

```
A,diamonds,\U0001F0C1,14
A,clubs,\\U0001F0D1,14
```

I have next OUT:

```
[qw@qw project]$
\U0001F0C1
\\U0001F0D1
<class 'str'>
```

Please help, I can't solve the problem.

Comment: Any reason not to put in the  character directly in the file?

Comment: Can you use the directly more like `print("♤")`? There are full card decks in unicode

Comment: We have no idea on original file. And its encoding. Please specify explicitly the encoding on every `open` (it helps also to document expectations). Note if the file contain \ as \, U as U, and the hexcode as alphanumeric code, you have text not an unicode character: you must "unescape" it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because the file is read without executing unicode escapes. You can execute them manually using `eval` like this: `d[2] = eval("'" + d[2] + "'")`. You have to add quotes to start and end of string to make it a string literal for evaluation. Final code would look like this:

```
import re 
file = open("arrayOfCards",'r')
while True:
    next_line = file.readline()
    if not next_line:
        break;
    d = next_line.split(',')
    d[2] = eval("'" + d[2] + "'")
    print (re.sub(r'\'','',d[2]))
file.close()

card = ['A','diamonds','\U0001F0C1','14']
print (type(card[2]), card[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion around unicode and escaping characters with `\`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import re

f = StringIO(r"""A,diamonds,\U0001F0C1,14
A,clubs,\\U0001F0D1,14""")

for l in f.readlines():
    d = l.split(',')
    c = re.sub(r'\\\\',r'\\',d[2])      # replacing double with single slash (like in 2nd line)
    print(c.encode().decode('unicode-escape')) # interpreting your unicode string while taking escaped \U into consideration

card = ['A','diamonds','\U0001F0C1','14']
print(type(card[2]), card[2])
```

Note: if you don't need further substitutions, you can leave `import re` and replace `re.sub(...)` with `c = d[2].replace('\\\\','\\')`